# Passing Screen Width to Controller in Silverstripe

Tags: javascript, php, silverstripe

I've working on a Silverstripe project where I want different sized images to load dependent on the width of the screen.

For example the template code could look like this:

```
<img src="$BackgroundImage.SetWidth($ScreenWidth).URL"/>
```

If I was using standard PHP I could run some Javascript that returns the screen width as post information or places it in a cookie which could be accessed via PHP.

In Silverstripe the template is pre-rendered before any javascript is run so I can't work out how to pass the screen width information to the Controller.

How should I go about this?

Comment: Have a look at this module: 
https://github.com/heyday/silverstripe-responsive-images

Comment: @3dgoo - it's a fullscreen gallery app so I'm wanting to resize images to the screen width by the closest 50 pixels. That module is a good option if I can't work out another method.

Answer (score 1):

This module should do the trick -https://github.com/heyday/silverstripe-responsive-images/

Answer (score 0):

You can actually do the same. You could check within the controller if you got a screen width with the current request:

- If the screen width is missing you just return a page containing a JavaScript to determine the screen width and either adding a get parameter to the current URL and forward to the new URL, running a post request with the screen width as parameter in JS to the same controller or just refresh the page if after setting a cookie.
- If the parameter is set because it was done in the previous step you can just display your page with the adjusted background image.